# Error starting a TFS Build Service in interactive mode

Tags: tfs, build, coded-ui-tests

Following this Documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712(vs.110).aspx#interactive) I tried to change an existing TFS Build Service to run as an Interactive Service. I followed the Documentation, I didn't change anything, except the checkbox "Start the Server Interactively" and pressed "Start". 
After pressing start I get the following Error in a Messagebox:

> Not all the information is correct. Fix it and try again

After that message I have to close it and close the service property window without saving the changes and without starting the service.

I also tried to unregister the the service and register it completly new directly as an Interactive Service. But that new server doesn't start, even the agents configured on that service don't start.

The existing non interactive service is running really fine bat can't start coded UI tests. I need the interactive mode to run coded UI tests

What is the problem with the TFS in this case? Is there a issue with TFS 2012 (I never got this problem in TFS2010)? Do I need another configuration in the TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Build Service user account have permissions to log on as an interactive session?  I assume your personal account does since you're RDP'ing into the server, I suggest trying to temporarily change the build service account to your personal account and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Dylan, yes, the build service user account is an user account, which can logon via rdp. this is because we want to test with an existing user context